# AngularJS - no two way binding for key-value object

Tags: angularjs

Just for note, I know nothing about angularJS, I worked with knockoutJS before and when it comes to angular I am just making assumptions.

I have code like this:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("recallCtrl",
function ($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.dcList = { 
        key: "value",
        abc: "aaaa",
        prop: "tadaa!"
    }
});
```

and markup as follows:

```
    <div ng-controller="recallCtrl">
        <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <th>Key</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in dcList">
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="key" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="value"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <pre>{{dcList | json}}</pre>
  </div>
```

So shouldn't output of `dcList` in the end of html change it's values when I edit corresponding inputs which as I assume are bound to object?

If I am doing something wrong, please advise. I want to create object and be able to change its keys and values.

Comment: You should declare you module like this:  `angular.module("umbraco", [])`. You forgot the square parenthesis, you were basically requesting the module not declaring it. I hope it fixes your problem!

Comment: `ng-model` evaluates relative to the current scope which in this case is localized to the `ng-repeat`. I don't think you can change the *key*, but the *value* is getting updated - you're just not seeing it because it's not affecting the `dcList` object on the parent. In order to update the *value* of the property on `dcList` you would have to use `ng-model="dcList[key]"` within your `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @Peter_Fretter not in this case, as I said I know absolutely nothing about angular and how it works, just assumptions, but I am using Umbraco CMS which is build with help of angular, there for I assume that I am injecting my piece of code into existing piece of ng, thats why I don't have ng-app declaration and if I set square parenthesis it just breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your current code isn't working is because the "key" and "value" variables are scoped within the `ng-repeat`, and no longer refer directly to the original object.

Keeping the "values" attached is easy, just use `dcList[key]` instead of `value`.  Adding new keys takes a bit more work; here I've attached an `ng-blur` to each "key" field which will init a new key when the field blurs. (`ng-change` would create a new field on every keystroke, which isn't what you want.)   Note that when you start typing a new key, its value appears to disappear -- this is because the `dcList[key]` refers to the new key name immediately.  This would be somewhat confusing in a real UI, of course; you'd probably want to code different behavior into the `createNewKey` function (such copying the old value into the new key, or deleting the original key).

```js
function recallCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dcList = { 
        key: "value",
        abc: "aaaa",
        prop: "tadaa!"
    }
    
    $scope.createNewKey = function(k) {
      $scope.dcList[k]="";
    }

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="recallCtrl">
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in dcList">
            <td>
                <input ng-model="key" ng-blur="createNewKey(key)"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="dcList[key]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <pre>{{dcList | json}}</pre>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation :) I think I can adjust it for my needs.

Comment: `key` and `value` don't turn into primitives as you've suggested. You can verify this by adding `{{key}}` and `{{value}}` directly beside the `<input>` elements in the OP's original code. You will see that as you update the value in the `<input>` the corresponding `key` or `value` is updated as well.

Comment: @Lex, you're right; thank you for that.  I'll correct the answer.

Answer (score 2):

please test this code, change in the value corresponding to the key,

```js
    angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.dcList = { 
        key: "value",
        abc: "aaaa",
        prop: "tadaa!"
    }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in dcList">
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="key" disabled/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="dcList[key]" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <pre>{{dcList | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UT2aln0eOh8FRFqWlD8z?p=preview)

Comment: This only answers half the question.

Comment: yes, as changing the keys of the hash is not the correct thing, i disabled the keys for now, I am just waiting if the questioner want me to extend my answer.

Comment: There is no need for that, I already figured out why is it a bad idea, haven't done anything like that before so I didn't think of weird but expected UI behavior, thanks for explanation.

Comment: "changing the keys of the hash is not the correct thing" Eh? It's not the *easy* thing, but it's certainly reasonable for someone to want to know how to do that.

Comment: yes, that's correct. I never said you did the wrong thing. :)